# How to Compare 2 DataFrame which different Column Names( Columns are in same Sequence) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The requirement is to compare 2 dataframe(dataset) both having different header. Basically I am querying database(HANA) table and comparing its output with the output of a SQL code as data testing

Ex

df1:

```
customerNo  City   Amount
C1          ABC     100
C2          XYZ     50
```

df2:

```
customer   Place   Amount
C1          ABC     100
C2          PQR     40
```

Although column names are different but they are in the correct order. Is there a way to compare dataset just based on column orders?

I tried `datacompy.Compare(df1,df2, on_index=True)` but its not working.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: When you query your database, can you not rename columns/identifiers? I see [HANA supports SQL](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20a6791f751910148d2bfe3814192a01.html) which allows for column aliasing.

Comment: @harvpan Output should be a boolean expression, which tells if both dataframes are matching or not

Comment: @Parfait: I can not rename, there are not just 2 dataframes I have to compare. I am building an automation tool to automate data validaiton by compare resulted of expected query and the actual query

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the columns and then running your compare tests. 
An example for renaming columns:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'customer':'customerNo','Place':'city','Amount':'Amount'})
```

Comment: Hi Harsha, Thanks for your reply. These are not just 2 data frames i need compare. Like this, there will be many datafrmaes I need to compare as part of validation.